# Epipe error with VS code terminal and git bash

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm trying to set up vscode with git-bash as the default terminal following https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal . I have set up my workspace with the following code in settings.json:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\python.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Git2\\bin\\sh.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login -i"]
}
```

After restarting, if I hit View - > Integrated terminal, The terminal flashes open for a split second and closes. I see the screenshot

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\python.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Git2\\bin\\sh.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login","-i"]
}
```